# Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

On MYSQL Workbench, I'm running this query : `count(*) from test.nameTable` I have couple millions rows in this table .
after a while I get this error : `Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

I saw this question and its answers in other places but none of the answers helped.
I tried setting all timeout and packet size global variables to their maximum value, and spliting my query somehow..
But none of this methods worked.

```
SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=10000000
SET GLOBAL net_read_timeout=10000000
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824
```

Anyone knows what could be the problem and how to solve it please?

Comment: Do the count on an indexed column

Comment: Is indexed column different then any other column?
I tried on a primary key - and it didnt work either

Comment: What storage type is the table (MyISAM, InnoDB, etc)? I seem to remember that can make quite a difference for COUNT...

Comment: The storage engine is InnoDB

Comment: Are you running the client on the server, or from another machine? If from another machine, I have seen this type of error caused by something completely unrelated to MySQL: Firewall NAT timeout of 5 minutes. Needless to say, for a query to take 5 minutes, something is wrong, but I have seen this timeout caused by that before.

Comment: I;m running it from the server - from mySQL workbench

Answer (score 3):

If you are running from MySQL Workbench (as I can read on your comment, please update question), the program have their own timeouts.

If you go to the program menu, preferences -> SQL Editor, you have these options:

MySQL Session:
DBMS connection keep-alive interval (in seconds):
DBMS connection read time out (in seconds):
DBMS connection time out (in seconds):

If you read descriptions from these options, you can see on the second one there's the time who workbench wait for a response from server.

Answer (score -1):

If no row were ever deleted from the table, th primary key would describe the total count of rows, in which case you could probably try

```
SELECT MAX(pk) FROM test.nameTable
```

Not sure it would be faster, but maybe worth the try?